# How can I add text to a video file?

Tags: video-editing

There are many **video editing** programs, but they all seem **complex** and install a lot of capabilities that I don't need, as long as all I want is to **place some text** on different moments of my video file.

Isn't there a simple way to do this?

Both Windows and Linux solutions are accepted.
No problem with a solution working from command line.

Additional Points:

In order to help writing the answers, I would like to add some example case (assuming `ffmpeg` could do this):

```
ffmpeg MyVideo.mp4 --add-text "FooFoo" --time 0:09:12
```

... that would add the **text** `FooFoo` at the photogram on **minute** 09, **second** 12.

Comment: Perhaps writing a subtitle file wouldn't do bad. Or, packaging this subtitle file with your video would be great. // Just an alternative.

Comment: Do you need to overlay some text on moments in the file OR insert a few frames of text, (the old dialogue card stile from before sound)?

Comment: @Firelord, your suggestion is acceptable for many cases. You should write it as an answer. The only problem comes with people that doesn't know how to open a .srt file, or with video players that don't read it.

Comment: @SteveBarnes, overlaying the text would be better, but the other option would to save my day.

Comment: You can use [**Avidemux**](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) to hard-code srt subs to the video. Just write the srt file with correct timing.

Answer (score 1):

For a free and good windows 7 answer you could use movie maker. It is very minimalist in what it can do, but you can easily do what you are asking. I've done it for a few sign language videos my daughter did (to out English words to her signs).

Answer (score 0):

You could use ffmpeg to add subtitles as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672809/use-ffmpeg-to-add-text-subtitles) SO questions answers or to split the video into chunks, (before and after each text bit), and use gimp to generate caption cards to insert between them.

There was also a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/713498/how-to-show-overlay-image-in-a-certain-time-span-with-ffmpeg) on superuser that suggested:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,1,2)'" output.mp4
```

Would use `watermark.pgn` as an overlay on a section of a video.

Comment: I have added an example case to the original question, in order to help in writing the answers. Could you please edit yours according?